# Jenkins is taking more than expected time to kick start any job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins is taking more than expected time (around 120 sec.) to kick start any job. Has anyone came across same?

Comment: Any chance that you have "Quiet period" set in your job's configuration?

Comment: Please post your `Jenkinsfile` and other information that may help

Comment: @nikodamn Quit period is set to 0 in configuration.

Comment: @Vadim FYR below is log, it is taking 2 min to start  : 
12:14:46 Started by user Saurabh

12:16:52 [EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.

12:16:52 [EnvInject] - Preparing an environment for the build.

Comment: @saurabh and what about you `Jenkinsfile`?

Comment: We are not using pipeline-as-code, so there is no jenkinsfile. Our Jenkins Tool is installed on Linux server and we have scheduled jobs on Jenkins to run shell scripts present on Linux server @Vadim Kotov